# require wp-load.php from Bedrock

Tags: php, wordpress

What's the best way to require wp-load.php from a standalone PHP file?

Should I include the autoloader in the /vendor folder?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This may help: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47049/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-wordpress-functions-outside-wordpress-files